# Transpose/Pivot Excel file in Pentaho (using multiple files)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I've been having some trouble with the following situation: There's an Excel file I need to use which has the information in the following format:

```
ColumnA  |  ColumnB
Name     |  John    
Business | Pentaho    
Address  | Evergreen 123    
Job type | Food processing    
NameBoss | Boss lv1    
Phone    | 555-NoPhone    
Mail     | thisATmail
```

What I need to do is get all column A as different columns, ending with 7 different columns, each one with one value, which is the data in column B. Additionally, the integration is reading the filename as an extra output field:

```
SELECT
'${FILES_ROOT}/proyectos/BUSINESS_NAME/B_NAME_OPER/archivos_fuente/NÓMINA BAC - ' ||nombre_empresa||'.xlsx' as nombre_archivo
--, nombre_empresa
FROM "public".maestro_empresa
```

The transformation for the Excel file I have it as this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

As can bee seen, in the fields tab of the transformation, added manually each column, since the data in the Excel file does not has headers.
With this done, I am not sure how to proceed from here in order to get the transposed data I need. What can I do?

End result I am looking forward is something like this:

```
Name | Business | Address       | Job type        | NameBoss | Phone       | Mail       | excel_name
John | Pentaho  | Evergreen 123 | Food processing | Boss lv1 | 555-NoPhone | thisAtMail | ExcelName.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With step 'Row demoralizer', you can do this easily. AT first you need to take input from excel file -> you need to use 'Row demoralizer' step. You can see sample from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Exu8mvdUdq8JgrYGr72U8Hjhh_1m9itY?usp=sharing).
Note: Remove ''Id'' column from my sample if you always suppose to get one line.

[image]

If you ColumnA values are dynamic /not specific . You can use [THIS](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bFHt7BzSRp0yjo7PQ_BfKSkyEIetl6tQ?usp=sharing) Metadata Injection sample ( where you need to take same excel input twice. But not require to specify column name). Please run transformation "MetaDataInjectionPV.ktr"

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the example. It seems I was doing quite poorly on the row denormaliser (self taught with pentaho), and with this example managed to get what I wanted and ending creating the table I required. Again, thank you very much